# Sockets java sending object to c++ server

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I am using sockets and I have one c++ server and one java client.

My c++ server is waiting for a c++ struct like this one:

```
struct Testing{

    double  a;
    double  b;
    double  c;

};
```

And my server code looks like this:

```
int recvStruct(int fd)
{
    struct Testing test;
    int ibytes = sizeof(struct Testing);

    if (ibytes!=read(fd,&test,ibytes))
    {
        printf("Error read\r\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        dosomething();
```

Then in my java client, i created one class:

```
public class Testing{
    double a,b,c;

public Testing(double a, double b, double c){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    }
}
```

and for the last, my client java code is this one:

```
try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("ipaddress", 12345);

        OutputStream os= socket.getOutputStream();
        Testing object = new Object(1,2,3);
        os.writeObject(object);
        socket.close();

 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        /* e.printStackTrace();
        response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();*/
 } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        /*e.printStackTrace();
        response = "IOException: " + e.toString();*/
 } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
             try {
                 socket.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                /* e.printStackTrace();*/
             }
 }
```

My problem is that i always get that error read message.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `os` in your java example?

Comment: You can't expect anything about the layout of structures in C++. Just reading the stream of bytes into raw memory is not portable, and may likely ever work only by a lucky coincidence. Send and receive data in a specified format, then parse it into a structure.

Comment: "Doesn't work"...?

Comment: @StoryTeller: You can expect many things about the layout of "structures" in C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - None of which make the OP's attempt remotely correct.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Your code just *assumes* that your C++ `Testing` class consists of the exact same number of bytes, in the exact same order, as the result of Java's `OutputStream.writeObject` function.

`OutputStream.writeObject` isn't even a function to serialise the component bytes of its members; [it does much more than that](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/objectoutputstream_writeobject.htm):

> The class of the object, the signature of the class, and the values of the non-transient and non-static fields of the class and all of its supertypes are written.

In conclusion, given that there is no relationship between the two whatsoever, success is extremely unlikely.

Instead, **serialise** to your own known format, then **deserialise** into the language structure you require. Research the bolded terms for more information.

Comment: it might be worth noting that "your own known format" can simply be the three doubles, one after another, or name value pairs.

Comment: @ThijsSteel: Indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If your struct is a sequence of 3 double, assuming in C++ a double is 8 byte as in Java, you should send a sequence of 24 bytes.
To convert each double I would use:

```
long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(someDouble);
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
for(int offset = 0, shift = 7*8; 
        offset < bytes.length; 
        offset++, shift-=8)
        bytes[offset] = (byte)(bits >>> shift);
```

Comment: so, you think i have to use this with each double, and then store them 3 in something like `byte[] bytes = new byte[24];` and send this last byte structure ?

Comment: Yes. When the server receives the 24-bytes buffer you can use memcpy to your 3-double struct address (or maybe cast). I'm pretty sure that C++ doubles are IEEE compliant, as java double are, and the way I'm telling you preserve the IEEE double structure (sign,exponent,mantissa). I found that this procedure is the fastest way.